# How to distinguish CTL-D and CTL-C keyboard Interrupt in general?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

Consider my experience with command-line in Mac OS and Linux:
when I want to stop or terminate some programs,
I often have to try "CTL-C" & "CTL-D", in order to see which one actually works.

How can I be quite certain which one to use, without trying both every time?

What is the distinguishing meaning of "CTL-C" & "CTL-D" in UNIX environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to start is with the terminal settings.  While <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> are almost always assigned to the same function, the terminal driver can be changed.

To see this:

```
$ stty -a |for-paste
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

shows

```
intr = ^C
eof = ^D
```

i.e., `^C` (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) is assigned to `intr`, and `^D` (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) is assigned to `eof`.  In principle, any of those settings that `stty` shows can be modified.  It is not unusual to find `intr` set to different values on Unix systems.

These can be helpful reading as a start:

- [stty(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) (manual page)
- [stty](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) (POSIX)
- [Terminal Settings](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=73) (The Linux Tutorial)

but POSIX gives precise information:

- [11. General Terminal Interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11)
- [11.1.9 Special Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09)

> **EOF**
> Special character on input, which is recognized if the **ICANON** flag is set. When received, all the bytes waiting to be read are immediately passed to the process without waiting for a *`<newline>`*, and the EOF is discarded. Thus, if there are no bytes waiting (that is, the EOF occurred at the beginning of a line), a byte count of zero shall be returned from the read(), representing an end-of-file indication. If **ICANON** is set, the **EOF** character shall be discarded when processed.
>
> **INTR**
> Special character on input, which is recognized if the **ISIG** flag is set. Generates a **SIGINT** signal which is sent to all processes in the foreground process group for which the terminal is the controlling terminal. If **ISIG** is set, the **INTR** character shall be discarded when processed.

That is, `EOF` tells the program that there is no more data to read.  `INTR` *signals* the program; the program actually decides what to do with this information.  To be more emphatic, you should send a `QUIT` which usually (again, program-dependent) tells the program to stop what it was doing.

These signals (SIGINT, SIGQUIT) can be caught by a program.  POSIX documents their conventional use in [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html)

Answer (score 2):

- [`CTRL-C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) is sending a [`SIGINT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT)
- [`CTRL-D`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character) is terminating the input stream

How a process react to either one is up to the process. If it does not read anything from input then CTRL-D may be ignored, perhaps not even noticed. On the other hand most processes will exit on SIGINT (the default behavior), but is ultimately up to the code to decide how it is handled. SIGINT is a signal, so it must somehow be handled (it immediately triggers the signal handling code in the process). CTRL-D does not explicitly trigger a reaction in the process, it simply causes End-Of-File when  (and if) the process is reading the input. Obviously CTRL-D will do nothing is the process input is redirected.

If you want to reliably kill it, use [`kill`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command))

Answer (score 0):

Ctl-C means "abort execution." Ctl-D means "end of file/end of input." You use one on a program that's waiting for input and the other on one that's refusing to wait for input.