# Why doesn't Control-D cause an EOFError in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, eoferror

Im trying to implement a program that enables a user to place an order, prompting them for items, one per line, until the user inputs control-d (which is a common way of ending one’s input to a program).
however when I press control d, in my terminal this appears "^D" and it doesn't exit, instead when i click enter after it it doesn't cause the EOFError to exit the program.

```
def main():
    menu = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
    }
    total = 0;
    while True:
        try:
            item = input("Item: ").title()
        except EOFError as e:
            print("\n")
            break
        except KeyError as k:
            print("key error occured")
        else:
            if menu.get(item) != None:
                total+= menu.get(item)
                print(f'Total: ${total:.2f}')
            


main()
```

I expected to exit loop when control d is pressed, but it just continues the loop

Comment: Your terminal doesn't appear to be interpreting Ctrl-d as a signal to close standard input. Python isn't going to raise `EOFError` if no file is actually closed.

Comment: What is your OS? Windows don't use Ctrl-d. it uses Ctrl-Z.

Comment: Window 11 , running the command on bash terminal

Comment: When you type Ctrl-Z in your terminal on Windows, does it work as you expected?

Comment: it simply prints ^Z , however Ctrl-C exits as expected

Comment: What IDE did you use to use the bash terminal?

Comment: the terminal used is within VScode IDE

Comment: I think your next question will be, `Why VScode IDE on Windows does not take Ctrl-Z?`. The answer is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1606368/ctrl-z-not-working-on-visual-studio-code-and-not-working-by-using-no-screen-ke).

Comment: If you `pip install readline` on Windows, then not only do you get convenient command-line editing capabilities, but it will recognize Ctrl-D as EOF.  By the way, the code in your `try` clause can never raise `KeyError`.  And `if item in menu:` is more readable and more efficient than using `.get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @chepner mentioned,

> Your terminal doesn't appear to be interpreting Ctrl-d as a signal to close standard input.

For your spec, which is **VScode IDE on Windows**, It doesn't interpret Ctrl-D(*Nix) sequence or Ctrl-Z(Windows) sequence as an EOF(End of File) in default.

Also, for Ctrl-C, you need to check whether it interrupts the process. [The interrupt signal and EOF signal differ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33773228/20307768). With the Ctrl-C sequence, `print("\n"); break` won't happen.

I'm not sure, but to use Ctrl-Z as an EOF in VScode IDE on Windows, check this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1606368/ctrl-z-not-working-on-visual-studio-code-and-not-working-by-using-no-screen-ke).